# Possible to run rails application with different ruby version on one server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a server which has rvm installed. I have some Rails applications running on the server the ruby version of these applications are 2.6.5. I would like to deploy some new Rails applications to this server. The point is the ruby version of these new applications are 3.1.2. I can install the ruby version 3.1.2 in my server but my question is: it is possible to run some Rails applications with one ruby version along side some other Rails applications with different ruby version on one server? I know it is possible to have different Rails version with one ruby version, but I am not sure whether we can have two different ruby versions and related applications along side each other in one server.

Comment: This is a textbook example for using a Ruby version manager, like [`RVM`](https://rvm.io/) or [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv).

Comment: I use rvm and passenger in my servers in production, to host apps on multiple versions of ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I use to use RVM (system-wide) to run multiple Rails apps using different Ruby and Rails versions.

**Application Setup**

Create Gemset: `$ rvm use 2.7.2-rg316@arsgh --create`

Create .ruby-version file: `$ echo 2.7.2-rg316 > .ruby-version`

Create .ruby-gemset file: `$ echo arsgh_rls5 > .ruby-gemset`

Install Rails version to gemset: `$ gem install rails -v 5.2.6.3`

Create new Rails app: `$ rails new arsgh --database=mysql`

Copy .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset files to application root.

**Apache's httpd.conf file and using Phusion Passenger**

Make sure you point to gemset: `PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2-rg316@arsgh/wrappers/ruby`

Answer (score 0):

In the `bin/rails` we have a comment like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

which states which ruby executable will be used.
So you can point to different ruby versions here. Some other files in `bin` folder can be modified like this.

But I'd suggest to use Docker to avoid problems with maintaining such environment. There are some good examples, like this [one](https://github.com/ledermann/docker-rails).